# How to forward SSRS report from the local report server to outside user

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm developing the C# .NET Web API application which should display the SSRS report which is located on another server. This reporting server does not have an external IP address. The server where the application will be deployed is on the same domain as the report server. The report server also requires the Windows Authentication. Is there a way to request the report page from the application server and send it to the user per user's request. Of course, functionality has to be the same (meaning that I don't need the screen shot of the report, but the report itself).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ReportViewer control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx You might have to change the authentication method.

Comment: Google "SSRS Subscriptions" and see if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @IanPreston: If it is impossible to do without changing the authentication, that is fine, but the client machine, which will access the application via the Internet, won't have an access to the report server, because the report server does not have an external IP address. So the question is: How to redirect user's request for the report.